# wrapping a parent element around every 3 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, parent-child

I'm just trying to wrap a div w class of slide around every 3 divs with a class of search-audio.

the one error i'm running into is that it's saying elem.parentElement is undefined...

So  part works great...

```
const audioBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.search-audio');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const audioBlockArr = Array.from(audioBlocks);

function groupBlocks(arr, len) {

    let groups = [],
        i = 0,
        n = arr.length;
  
    while (i < n) {
      groups.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
    }
  
    return groups;
  }

newArr = [...groupBlocks(audioBlockArr, 3)];
```

The trouble is here - wrapping a div around the new array of grouped elements.

```
let wrap = (array) => {
  
  array.forEach((elem) => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('slide');
    div.innerHTML = '';

    elem.parentElement.insertBefore(div, elem);
    div.appendChild(elem);
  });
}

wrap(newArr);
```

Full code:

```js
const audioBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.search-audio');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const audioBlockArr = Array.from(audioBlocks);

function groupBlocks(arr, len) {

  let groups = [],
    i = 0,
    n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    groups.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return groups;
}

newArr = [...groupBlocks(audioBlockArr, 3)];

let wrap = (array) => {
  array.forEach((elem) => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('slide');
    div.innerHTML = '';

    elem.parentElement.insertBefore(div, elem);
    div.appendChild(elem);
  });
}

wrap(newArr);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-audio {
  height: 12rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background: rgb(255, 153, 0);
  margin: .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slide {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="search-audio 1"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 2"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 3"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 4"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 5"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 6"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 7"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 8"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 9"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 10"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 11"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 12"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 13"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 14"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 15"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 16"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 17"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 18"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 19"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 20"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why dont you just simply change your html to your needs? Sounds like a [x/y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem to me

Comment: If you're willing to use jQuery, it has nice `.wrap()` and `.wrapWith()` methods that can do this easily. If not, you can read the source code to see how it does it.

Comment: thanks @Barmar. I can't use jQuery for this particular project unfortunately. It has to be vanilla javascript.

Comment: I addressed that in my "If not" sentence.

Comment: @Marc - the information is being pulled from a database table in php; i'm not writing it directly. That and for various other reasons, I need to be able to use JS for this.

Comment: @Barmar. I have - the issue i've posted is based on the same logic. but i'm getting one error, as i've described.

Comment: `elem` isn't an element, it's an array of 3 elements. What do you expect `elem.parentElement` to be?

Comment: i'm trying to wrap a parent element of div.slide around each array of 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `elem` isn't a single element, it's an array of 3 elements that was created by `groupBlocks()`. So there's no `elem.parentElement`.

Use `elem[0].parentElement` to get the common parent of the all the elements. And then loop over them to append each element to the new div.

I've renamed `elem` to `group` in the code below, to more correctly match what it contains.

```js
const audioBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.search-audio');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const audioBlockArr = Array.from(audioBlocks);

function groupBlocks(arr, len) {

  let groups = [],
    i = 0,
    n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    groups.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return groups;
}

newArr = [...groupBlocks(audioBlockArr, 3)];

let wrap = (array) => {
  array.forEach((group) => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('slide');
    div.innerHTML = '';

    group[0].parentElement.insertBefore(div, group[0]);
    group.forEach(elem => div.appendChild(elem));
  });
}

wrap(newArr);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-audio {
  height: 12rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background: rgb(255, 153, 0);
  margin: .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slide {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="search-audio 1"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 2"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 3"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 4"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 5"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 6"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 7"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 8"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 9"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 10"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 11"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 12"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 13"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 14"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 15"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 16"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 17"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 18"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 19"></div>
    <div class="search-audio 20"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating it a bit, it could be possible just using CSS for this by using `:nth-child` to apply the styles of `.search-audio` to every 3rd div of class `.slide`.

This code might be wrong but something like:

```css
.slide:nth-child(3n) {
  /* move styles here from .search-audo */
}
```

Here's a few links that might be useful to learn how to use them:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this requires a JS solution bc of further functionality I have to implement that I haven't placed in this post. This is a highly simplified version of what I'm trying to do, but long-story short. It has to be done in JS

Answer (score 0):

First a note: classNames can not be a number (`class="search-audio 1`).

Here is a snippet that groups the elements in groups of 3 using a reducer and then wraps those groups in a grouping element.

```js
// create groups of 3
const sliderGroups = [...document.querySelectorAll(`.search-audio`)]
  .reduce((acc, el, i) => {
    if (i && i%3 == 0) {
      acc = [...acc, []];
    }
    acc[acc.length - 1] = acc[acc.length - 1].concat(el);
    return acc;
  }, [[]]);
// now you have an array of arrays 
// with each 3 elements. Let's wrap
// those
wrap(sliderGroups);

function wrap (array) {
  // a wrapper base Node
  const wrapperElem = Object.assign(
    document.createElement(`div`), {className: `slideGroup`});
  const sliderCollection = document.querySelector(`.slider`);
  array.forEach( elemGroup => {
    // create a new wrapper Node from the base
    const wrap = wrapperElem.cloneNode();
    // append it to div.slider
    sliderCollection.append(wrap);
    // append *moves* the (life) elements of
    // the current group to the wrap element
    wrap.append(...elemGroup);
  });
}
```

```css
.search-audio:after {
  content: "search-audio elem";
  color: red;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.slideGroup:before {
  content: "slide group";
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio]"></div>
    <div class="search-audio]"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
    <div class="search-audio"></div>
</div>
```